# python разделение строки

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, split

Вот имеется код:

```
inp = input()
inp = inp.split()
```

При вводе например:

```
newobj = obj(<параметры>)
или
newobj.<параметр> = 5
```

python должен разделить в первом случае

```
mass = ['newobj', '=', 'obj', '<параметры>']
```

во втором:

```
mass = ['newobj', '.', '<параметр>', '=', 5]
```

Только не спрашивайте, зачем мне это нужно)

Comment: Используйте регулярные выражения, например. Обычным split такое нельзя сделать.

Comment: @insolor можете подсказать, какие?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно уловил суть задачи, то можно попробовать следующие:

```
import re

def split_input(input_str):
    pattern = r'\.|\=|<.*?>|\w+'
    result = re.findall(pattern, input_str)
    for i in range(len(result)):
        try:
            result[i] = int(result[i])
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return result

# Строки из примера
input_1 = "newobj = obj(<параметры>)"
result = split_input(input_1)
print(result)

input_2 = "newobj.<параметр> = 5"
result_2 = split_input(input_2)
print(result_2)
```

Вывод:

```
['newobj', '=', 'obj', '<параметры>']
['newobj', '.', '<параметр>', '=', 5]

[Program finished]
```

[**Функция findall**](https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/modul-re-python/funktsija-findall-modulja-re/)

Answer (score 0):

Возможно найдутся более изящные способы, но самое простое решение - поиск ключевых элементов строки и разделение относительно них.

```
def StpdSplit(inp: str) ->list:
    outlist = []
    if "." in inp:
        outlist.append(inp[0:inp.find(".")])
        outlist.append(inp[inp.find(".")])
        inp = inp[inp.find(".")+1:]
        outlist.append(inp[0:inp.find(" = ")])
        outlist.append("=")
        inp = inp[inp.find(" = ") + 3:]
        outlist.append(inp)
        return outlist
    else:
        outlist.append(inp[0:inp.find(" = ")])
        outlist.append("=")
        inp = inp[inp.find(" = ") + 3:]
        outlist.append(inp[0:inp.find("(")])
        inp = inp[inp.find("(") + 1:]
        outlist.append(inp[0:inp.find(")")])
        return outlist
```

Comment: Слишком сложно...

Comment: @RodionMorozov алгоритм или синтаксис?

Comment: Алгоритм попроще не придумаю, а вот по синтаксису подсказать смогу.

Comment: мне бы регулярное выражение. там как то попроще мне)

Comment: Не встречал чего-то подходящего. Если появится информация - пните)

Comment: Хорошо) Найду что то - скажу

Comment: @dresqd это конечно забавный способ, но совершенно бесполезный. Стоит хоть сколько-нибудь изменить входящию строку и функция перестанет работать корректно. Решение должно быть универсальным, иначе какой смысл от него?